# В Intellij IDE junit тест запускается и проходит успешно. При попытке компиляции из командной строки - выдает кучу ошибок

Tags: java

Вот сам тест

```
package com.selenium.test.junit.tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import com.selenium.test.testng.listeners.ScreenShotOnFailListener;
import com.selenium.test.webtestsbase.WebDriverFactory;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.ElementFinder;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
/**
 * Created by Nosova Yuliia on 02.10.2015
 */
public class TestCD {

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    WebDriverFactory.startBrowser(true);
    }


    @Test
    public void Add() {


    WebDriverFactory.getDriver().get("http://cd2.php.attractgroup.com/");
    WebElement formHtml = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
    WebElement aInput = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"a_val\"]"));
    aInput.clear();
    aInput.sendKeys("3");
    WebElement formHtml2 = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
    WebElement bInput = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"b_val\"]"));
    bInput.clear();
    bInput.sendKeys("5");
    formHtml.submit();

    WebElement newHtml = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
    assertTrue("Value=8", newHtml.getText().contains("Value=8"));


}

@After
public void afterTest() {
    WebDriverFactory.finishBrowser();
}

}
```

Вот что выдает при компиляции:

```
    C:\Users\Yulia\IdeaProjects\TestYuliia\src\test\java\com\selenium\test\junit\tests>javac TestCD.java
TestCD.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
                   ^
TestCD.java:4: error: package com.selenium.test.testng.listeners does not exist
    import com.selenium.test.testng.listeners.ScreenShotOnFailListener;
                                     ^
  TestCD.java:5: error: package com.selenium.test.webtestsbase does not exist
   import com.selenium.test.webtestsbase.WebDriverFactory;
                                 ^
    TestCD.java:6: error: package com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven does not exist

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.ElementFinder;
                                      ^
TestCD.java:7: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                      ^
TestCD.java:8: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext;
                      ^
TestCD.java:9: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
                      ^
TestCD.java:10: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.After;
            ^
TestCD.java:11: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Before;
            ^
TestCD.java:12: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
            ^
TestCD.java:18: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
                   ^
TestCD.java:18: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
^
TestCD.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    @Before
 ^
  symbol:   class Before
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        @Test
         ^
      symbol:   class Test
      location: class TestCD
   TestCD.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    @After
     ^
  symbol:   class After
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriverFactory.startBrowser(true);
        ^
  symbol:   variable WebDriverFactory
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
              WebDriverFactory.getDriver().get("http://cd2.php.attractgroup.com/");
        ^
  symbol:   variable WebDriverFactory
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement formHtml =     WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
        ^
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement formHtml = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable By
   location: class TestCD
 TestCD.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement formHtml = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
                          ^
  symbol:   variable WebDriverFactory
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement aInput = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"a_val\"]"));
         ^
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement aInput = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"a_val\"]"));
                                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable By
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement aInput = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"a_val\"]"));
                        ^
  symbol:   variable WebDriverFactory
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement formHtml2 = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
        ^
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement formHtml2 = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable By
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement formHtml2 = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
                           ^
  symbol:   variable WebDriverFactory
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement bInput = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"b_val\"]"));
        ^
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement bInput = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"b_val\"]"));
                                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable By
  location: class TestCD
 TestCD.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement bInput = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=\"b_val\"]"));
                        ^
  symbol:   variable WebDriverFactory
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
       WebElement newHtml = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
        ^
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement newHtml = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable By
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement newHtml = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
                         ^
  symbol:   variable WebDriverFactory
  location: class TestCD
TestCD.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriverFactory.finishBrowser();
        ^
  symbol:   variable WebDriverFactory
  location: class TestCD
33 errors
```

Answer (score 2):

[Classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)). IDEA как и любая другая IDE за вас занимается передачей всех нужных параметров при запуске, если же вы запускаете вручную, надо так же самим заботиться о classpath и вообще о всём энвайроменте для JVM. [Офф. дока](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)